# Showing that a function in a measure space does not converge in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathbb{X}, \mu)$ be a measure space. A sequence of real-valued measurable functions $(f_n)$ is said to **converge in measure** to a real-value measurable function $f$ if

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x) - f(x)|\ge \alpha\})=0$$

for all $\alpha>0$.

I have to prove that $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ converges pointwise to $f=0$ and that it does not converge in measure.

I have shown that it does converge pointwise but I don't know how to show that it doesn't converge in measure to any function.

If it converges in measure then it must converge in measure to $f=0$? If so, then assuming that it does converge in measure, for $\alpha=1$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x) - f(x)|\ge \alpha\}) = \mu(\{x\in X:\chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)\ge 1\})=\mu([n,n+1])=1$ (I'm assuming Lebesgue measure), a contradiction.

But I'm struggling to prove this assumption.

Comment: Proof: It's easy to show that it's not a Cauchy sequence in measure. Hence it doesn't converges in measure: math.stackexchange.com/questions/789816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start by saying, we assume that $f_n$ converges in measure to some function $f$.

Fix some $R>0$, then we have for $n>R$ and every $\alpha >0$
$$ \mu(\{ x \in X  \ : \ \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert \geq \alpha \}) 
\geq \mu(\{ x \in [-R,R]  \ : \ \vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert \geq \alpha \}) 
= \mu(\{ x\in [-R,R] \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert \geq \alpha \}). $$
However, the RHS is independend of $n$ and the LHS goes to zero, thus, we get
$$ \mu(\{ x\in [-R,R] \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert \geq \alpha \}) =0 $$
for every $\alpha >0$. This implies that $f=0$ a.e. on $[-R,R]$ as we have
$$ \mu(\{ x\in [-R,R] \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert \neq 0 \}) 
= \mu( \bigcup_{m\geq \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}}\{ x\in [-R,R] \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert \geq 1/m \}) 
= \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \mu( \{ x\in [-R,R] \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert \geq 1/m \}) 
= \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} 0 =0.
$$
However, $R>0$ was arbitrary, so we get that $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how did you get this inequality.

Comment: The inequality follows from the fact that $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in (-\infty, n)$.

Comment: I edited my answer, is it clearer now?

Comment: Sorry, now I'm trying to see why $f=0$ a.e. Which zero measure set $N$ for which $f$ is 0 in $[-R, R]\setminus N$?

Comment: This is a standard trick by taking suitable unions and then use that nested unions are the same as taking limits.